# Making XAML Grid width full screen

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I m creating Windows Phone 8.1 app with Visual Studio Where I m putting XAML grid but could not make full width. If I give width to each column then grid will be not full width in all resolution of Phone
My codes are as below

```
<ListView Name="lvData" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" 
                                    BorderThickness="1" Foreground="#000" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="_Number" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="1" x:Uid="_Dep" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="Arr" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                                <GridViewHeaderItem Grid.Column="3" x:Uid="CurrentStatus" Style="{StaticResource GridViewHeader}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}" Content="{Binding Number}"/>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}" Content="{Binding DepTime}" />
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}" Content="{Binding ArrTime}"/>
                                <GridViewItem Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource GridViewItem}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" Content="{Binding CurrentStatus}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

My Style

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewHeaderItem" x:Key="GridViewHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#48649F"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#000"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stretch `HorizontalContentAlignment` of `ListViewItem`:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      ...
</ListView>
```